# Validation of single checkbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a form that should not be submitted until the user has ticked the terms and conditions checkbox (`chkTerms`). What is the best way to prevent submission of the form if it is unticked?

I would have put a call to a JavaScript function in the form tag but for various reasons this is embedded in my master page so I assume this is a no go.  Can this be done in jQuery for instance?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable your submit button on form load.
Only enable it when checkbox is ticked and again disable it on uncheck of checkbox.

Check the example below:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" disabled="true" value="Submit"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" onchange="submitStatus();">Terms and Conditions</input>
```

and your script function should be

```
function submitStatus(){
  if(document.getElementById('chk').checked){
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled = false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should probably give your user some feedback as to what is causing the button to be disabled, but yes, this is another good approach.

Comment: Thanks! I used a variation of this in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in jQuery this is very easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(e){ // when the form is loaded
        if (!$('input[name="chkTerms"]')[0].checked) { // if the input with the name "chkTerms" is not checked
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submission
            // provide feedback to the user in some way
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use jquery validate

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to do it using JQuery bcoz if u disable a button and enable only on checkbox click, user may not know the button will get enabled only if the checkbox is checked.You can use the same coding which is mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is actually that once the button is 'enabled' all my other validation is bypassed and the form submits anyway...

Comment: Try entering this as a comment rather than an answer.  You'll get better feedback that way.